# How do I convert datepicker returned date format to a different format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, date-format, angular-material

Sorry about the bad title, I didn't exactly know how to phrase that any better. I'm going to try to explain what I need as best as possible.

I'm currently making a Task Manager (a ToDo list) in Javascript where you can create tasks, set a schedule for them and then you would have a list with all the tasks that you need to do and the respective schedule of each task (beginning and ending date).

I'm using **Angular.js** and **Angular Material** to do my UI. I have the Angular Material's datepicker. This is the code I use to get the date value:

```
angular.module('KBTM_App', ['ngMaterial']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.myDate1 = new Date();

...

// This is where I get the date value
var initial_date_1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-controller="AppCtrl"]')).scope().myDate1;
```

The problem is that this datepicker is returning the date in this format:"2016-04-29T08:36:10.027Z", which I don't want. I want a more normal format, like "DD-MM-YYYY".

I tried converting the date format with **Moment.js**, but that didn't work. Here's the code I used for that:

```
var initial_date = moment(initial_date_1, "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:MM:SS.SSS'Z'").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

And then I would store that date in the localStorage:

```
// Get the other dates already in the list
var initial_dates = get_initial_dates();

// Adds the new date to that list
initial_dates.push(initial_date);

// Stores those dates in the localStorage
localStorage.setItem('initial_date_db', JSON.stringify(initial_dates));
```

With that code I get "**Invalid date**" when trying to add a new task to the task list.

Sorry for the long post!

Thanks to whoever can help me.

Comment: Have you already tried the date-format="" Option ???

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm a Javascript beginner, so I searched online and found that most people recommended using moment.js for things like this.

Comment: @T.Ferreira Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date format in html using angular material datepicker by using following code.

```
 data-ng-value="myDate1  | date : 'shortDate'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the angular date filter to format the date. Refer the link [angular date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
var  initial_date = $filter('date')($scope.myDate1, "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Inject the $filter in your controller main module.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle dates is to use `momentjs` and there is a special AJS Directive available. [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)
You can check `[momentjs][2]` offical docs for detailed info. You have to add `angular-moment` as dependency injection to use moment easily. https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#instructions-for-using-moment-timezone-with-webpack